# How to generate files conditionally when Git is selected?

Tags: qt-creator, wizard

To speed up my workflow with Qt Creator I create a custom project wizard in JSON format, as part of which I add a [Summary page](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html#summary):

```
{
    "trDisplayName": "Project Management",
    "trShortTitle": "Summary",
    "typeId": "Summary"
}
```

Within the [File generator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html#file-generator) I copy two files, i.e. `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`, to the project directory:

```
{
    "source": ".gitattributes",
    "target": "%{TargetPath}/.gitattributes"
},
{
    "source": ".gitignore",
    "target": "%{TargetPath}/.gitignore"
}
```

Written like that, the files are always copied, even when Git is not selected as a version control system. I want the files to be copied only if they are needed.

The documentation for the *Summary page* says:

> It sets VersionControl to the ID of the version control system in use

but no further info is added about the `VersionControl` variable and its values.

How to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you the following solution:

1. Assign a keyboard shortcut to the `Wizard.Inspect` command by going to

   *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts*
2. Start the custom wizard and navigate to the *Summary page*
3. Press the selected schortcut

   This will open a window that lists all of the defined fields and variables in the wizard at the time the action was triggered. There you can find:

   ```
   Key            | Type    | Value | Eval
   VersionControl | QString | G.Git | G.Git
   ```
4. Having this information, change the *File generator* code like this:

   ```
   {
       "source": ".gitattributes",
       "target": "%{TargetPath}/.gitattributes",
       "condition": "%{JS: '%{VersionControl}' === 'G.Git'}"
   },
   {
       "source": ".gitignore",
       "target": "%{TargetPath}/.gitignore",
       "condition": "%{JS: '%{VersionControl}' === 'G.Git'}"
   }
   ```